# Input App List of sites accessed

Tags: mergin-maps

We are looking at using Lutra Consulting's Input App on some IOS devices that have website restrictions.  Wondering if anyone has a list of sites that this app needs to communicate with so that we can have them white listed.

Answer (score 1):

The app requires to communicate with https://public.cloudmergin.com/

The Mergin service is used as a storage, synchronisation and collaborative editing. Without that, for the iOS version of the Input app, you will have difficulty to get data in and out of your device.

If you have any problems, do not hesitate to contact us directly.